# PL/SQL from Oracle SQL Developer connecting to DB2

Tags: oracle, plsql, db2, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have successfully connected to a DB2 database from Oracle SQL Developer 19.4.0.354 using the DB2 ODBC driver.
SQl scripts work just fine.

Now I also want to execute PL/SQL scripts but simple sample script fails.:

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
message  varchar2(20):= 'Hello, World!';
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line(message);
END;
```

It fails in such a way that PL/SQL code does not seem to be accepted at all:

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=DECLARE
message  varchar2(20):= 'Hell;BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT;<create_view>, DRIVER=4.26.14
```

Is PL/SQL generally supported in this setup?

Comment: I don't know DB2, but the [documentation page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.plsql.doc/doc/c0053607.html) I found says *'PL/SQL statement execution is not enabled from these interfaces by default. PL/SQL statement execution support must be enabled on the DB2 data server.'*

Comment: @WilliamRobertson: thanks for response! I have executed "db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=800" as advised in the DB2 documentation so PL/SQL"statements can be compiled and executed using data server interfaces".

Comment: for full compatibility, not only must the DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR db2-registry variable be set to ORACLE, and the instance bounced, but also the *database* has to be created __AFTER__ those changes.  That's what's documented in the Db2 Knowledge Centre. Otherwise the compatibility is limited.

Comment: @mao - may I suggest you post your comment as an answer? It encapsulates some knowledge which others may find useful, and we prefer answered questions over questions with comments but no answers.

Answer (score 0):

When using the Oracle-compatibility mode of Db2-LUW, it is necessary to:

- set the Db2-registry-variable DB2_COMPATIBILITY=ORA with the db2set command.
- bounce the Db2-instance with the `db2stop` and `db2start` commands, so the registry variable becomes effective.
- create a new database **after** both of the above steps are completed (using the `db2 create database command` ), so that Oracle specific datatypes and other features become available.

If you only change the registry variable and bounce the Db2-instance but use a pre-existing database then you will not get all of the implemented Oracle compatibility features!  This is documented in the Db2-Knowledge-Centre online.

With currently shipping Db2-LUW versions, you cannot retrofit the Oracle compatibility on to a previously created database.

Comment: the (re-)creation of a database is of course quite a show-stopper in a corporate environment.